# How can I plot Vout for dual band RF Rectifier circuit design in ADS

Tags: ads

[image: when I am plotting the Vout graph, this is the graph I am getting.]

How can I plot Vout for dual band RF Rectifier circuit design in ADS..when I am plotting the Vout graph, this is the graph I am getting

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.